# Compton scattering electron recoil energy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, electrons, scattering

I need to show that the recoil electron energy is:

$$ \varepsilon = mc^2 + \frac{(2\alpha  \cos^2\phi)h\nu}{(1+\alpha)^2 - \alpha^2\cos
^2 \phi}$$

Where $\alpha = h \nu_0/mc^2$ and $\phi$ is the electron's momentum angle with relation to the incident photon. I've tried using the relation of $\theta$ and $\phi$ in the compton scattering equation, but I can't derive this one.

Answer (score 1):

Start with conservation of 4-momentum. Before scattering, the 4-momentum of the photon was $p_B^\mu = (h\nu_0/c, h\nu_0/c, 0, 0)$ and of the electron $P_B^\mu = (mc, 0, 0, 0)$. After the scattering, we have the photon's 4-momentum $p_A^\mu = (h\nu/c, h\nu\cos\theta/c, h\nu\sin\theta/c, 0)$ and electron's 4-momentum $P_A^\mu = (\varepsilon/c, P\cos\phi, P\sin\phi, 0)$. The 4-momentum conservation law says:
$$p_B^\mu + P_B^\mu = p_A^\mu + P_A^\mu.$$
You can obtain various relations between the initial and final energies, momenta, and scattering angles by rearranging the terms and taking the squares of both sides keeping in mind that $p^\mu p_\mu = 0$ and $P^\mu P_\mu = m^2c^2$ both before and after the scattering. For instance, rearrange the terms as
$$p_B^\mu - p_A^\mu = P_A^\mu - P_B^\mu.$$
Then, take squares of both sides:
$$-p_B^\mu p_{A\mu} = m^2c^2 - P_B^\mu P_{A\mu}.$$
Spelling out the products,
$$p_B^\mu p_{A\mu} = h^2\nu\nu_0(1 - \cos\theta)/c^2;$$
$$P_B^\mu P_{A\mu} = m\varepsilon.$$
From this, we obtain electron energy after scattering:
$$\varepsilon = mc^2 + h^2\nu\nu_0(1 - \cos\theta)/c^2$$
This expression does not look like the one you are trying to obtain, but I am sure it is derivable in this way if you have time and patience.

Comment: You could connect *θ* to *φ*  via equation (4) of [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_scattering#Derivation_of_the_scattering_formula). You get the OP's expression, or pretty close--I am not sure he has copied his expression correctly.